# AWS RDS query returning inconsistent results

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Running into the strangest issue with AWS RDS Serverless. I'm using the Data API to query the database. (Note: `id` is a primary key)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts;

= 28535
```

My API limits page size to 200 and these are the queries I'm making to the database.

```
SELECT id FROM accounts ORDER BY last_name ASC LIMIT 200 OFFSET 3600;

== contains a row with id 92778
```

Then the next page (`OFFSET 3800`),

```
SELECT id FROM accounts ORDER BY last_name ASC LIMIT 200 OFFSET 3800;

== ALSO contains a row with id 92778
```

What's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Realized my mistake after I posted the question.

```
SELECT id FROM accounts ORDER BY last_name, id ASC LIMIT 200 OFFSET 3600;
```

There's no guarantee on the order if there are multiple `last_name` with the same value. Added `id` as a secondary sort and that fixed it.